# When to use DBMS instead of System Files for Spatial Data Storage?

Tags: spatial-database, gis-principle

I'm having trouble deciding when it is best to use a DBMS instead of System Files for storage of Spatial Data.  Are there any specific guidelines and reasons for when one method is preferred over the other?

For example, does it depend on the number of users working with the data (single-user vs multi-user)? Or what is being done in a project (data storage/visualization vs processing analyses)?  Or is it personal preference in some respects?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Unfortunately, I think your question as it stands is too broad for our focussed Q&A format because, it falls under the [Help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) category of  `there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”`  The same page offers advice on how it might be possible to bring a question like this to be on topic.  I think what you may be wanting to know is "When to use a DBMS rather than system files for spatial data storage?" or "How to use a DBMS rather than system files for spatial analysis?"

Comment: Another, and currently under used, place to ask broad questions is the [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) of GIS SE.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the friendly suggestions! I've updated the question, and will keep the GIS Chat Room in mind for the future.